# Easy way to implement splash screen in React Native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, splash-screen

I am new to React-Native development. I try to implement a splash screen in my app. I tried a lot of options from the web but not get success because some of the code is outdated and some process is very confusing.

Comment: If you have searched react native splash screen, you would have gotten the package and the most updated codes for react-native-splashscreen. Is that not working for you too?

Comment: Can you confirm me this is the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: This is the tutorial that I followed last March when adding a splash screen to my RN app. https://medium.com/@appstud/add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-810492e773f9

Comment: Is there any way to display the splash image in full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [react-native-splash-screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen#readme) Sample code is below

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class WelcomePage extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // do stuff while splash screen is shown
        // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
}
```

To learn more see [examples](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/tree/master/examples)

To make `full screen`

```
On MainActivity.java, just like that:

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashTheme); // Add theme here 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


IN res/values/styles.xml

<resources>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

launch_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:src="@drawable/launch_screen" android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is there any way to display the splash image in full screen?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer please check

Comment: I tried your code but I didn't get success properly. Link: https://ibb.co/1sLbKg0

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [react-native-bootsplash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash) since it's still actively maintained.
Before implementing any library that asks you to add code to the Swift and Java bridge files it's a good idea to familiarize yourself with the RN folder structure. Once you understand the folder structure and some of the main files it becomes much easier to debug your app and you will be able to develop apps faster.

Comment: +1 for react-native-bootsplash.   The other one,  react-native-splash-screen, hasn't been updated for 2 years, so takes no account of Kotlin changes .